# STRING_AGG with line break

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;
CREATE TABLE items (item varchar(20));
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('apple'),('raspberry');
SELECT STRING_AGG(item, CHAR(13)) AS item_list FROM items;
```

[image]

How do I get a line break between items ?

Comment: *"How do I get a line break between items ?"* `CHAR(13)` is Carriage Return. `CHAR(10)` in a Line Feed. Change `CHAR(13)` to `CHAR(10)`? If you want both characters (to be explicit) use `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`.

Comment: The char(13) character is there... you just cannot see it in grid view. Click Query > Results to > Results to text from SSMS menu to view result in text mode.

Comment: `STRING_AGG(item, CHAR(10))` for linux style? Or `STRING_AGG(item, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))` for windows style?

Comment: @Salman: indeed thx, but oddly the string appears truncated.

Comment: SSMS also truncates varchar data to around x chars (opens SSMS settings)

Comment: By default results to `text` are limited to 256 characters per value. For Grid results, CR\LF characters are removed by default **on Copy**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your query is working fine on my environment. You need to enable this settings in the management studio:

[image]

```
Tools > Options > Query Results > Results to Grid
```

It makes no sense for me why, but they have changed the default behavior several SSMS releases ago.

Comment: Thx, good to know ! But even with CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), and after doing what you are suggesting, there is no line break in the grid. And even if I copy/paste from the result grid into a text editor, same result. I am running SSMS under windows.

Comment: @LudovicAubert Restart the studio.

Comment: This time, there are invisible line breaks in the grid. If I copy/paste from the grid into a text editor, they become visible in the editor. Thx !

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in the string:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(item, '
') AS item_list
FROM items;
```

One caveat is that the definition of "end of line" depends on the operating system.  So, this will insert a different value on Unix versus Windows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=847458b5995c897ba1a3748240f687d0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is no different to what the OP already has, apart from it is likely both a carriage return **and** line feed (depending on the environment you typed the above). The "problem" very likely stems from the fact the OP has the "Retain CR/LF on copy or save" option switched off in SSMS.

Comment: You have no idea how much this helped me! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If using the Management Studio Query Editor, the Results to Grid option cannot implement the carriage return. Switch to Results to Text to see the result set properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

SELECT STRING_AGG(item, CHAR(13)) AS item_list FROM items;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print` function for print all output as **text**

```
DECLARE @Res  NVARCHAR(MAX)  = (SELECT STRING_AGG(item, '
') FROM items);
print(@Res)
```